# My new host's PHP/Apache configuration is being wonky with my PHP scripts

Tags: php, apache

Originally, I had NameCheap hosting, and used that webserver to do development testing for a few of my PHP scripts that run for a decent amount of time.

The PHP script has a `while` loop that goes through several times, and each time, it echoes out information. It would echo this information out as it processed the page. I didn't need to `flush()` or `ob_flush()` or do anything with `output_buffering`. It simply worked well.

On the current hosting, any time I try to run my scripts, after a certain amount of time, I get a Server Internal Error. So I upped all the time constants in the php.ini file but it's literally making no difference. I also turned off output_buffering. I also looked at about 5 different Stack Overflow threads and used all possible solutions regarding `ob_flush`, `flush()`, including doing `ini_set()` in the beginning of the script to set the time.

Example:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time' ,0); 
ini_set('set_memory_limit', -1);

while (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
```

Originally, my PHP script would be able to run for hours on end on the Namecheap shared hosting, and it only had 90 max_execution_time. It also worked automatically by displaying all my echoed out information as it looped through.

I feel like the Apache configuration which I can't touch is very very downgraded from the Namecheap one. Or, I might just not have a PHP.ini file that even works. I don't know.

Also, every time I reload the page, it either goes in to a Server Internal Error, doesn't load the page at all, and if it does load the page, I have it set for now that the while loop only goes through 5 times, so I see the output of the loop 5 times, but it wouldn't dynamically echo through the page like last time.

Comment: Have you confirmed from phpinfo() if the settings you did in php.ini file did in fact take effect?

Comment: I just checked. It looks like it didn't affect it for whatever reason. I'm using the cPanel's PHP INI Editor. And the PHP.INI file is in the FTP folder as well, so why isn't it affecting it.